# Changing stroke colour using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, p5.js

I am struggling with the error of which throw me once I am trying to recursively change a colour. The error is: “Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined (sketch: line 18)” and reference to this piece of code: `this.color.levels.map(x => x * 0.9)` .

I supposed that’s because of a recursive and problem with “this” context. The “right” function which I’ve created executing just one time until above error is thrown.

Any ideas how to make this work or how to recursively change the colour referencing to the same object which I’ve been created?

My code: https://editor.p5js.org/grzegorz.kuguar@gmail.com/sketches/Syc1qQmnQ

```
<code> class Branch {
          constructor(begin, end, strokeW, color, angle) {
                this.begin = begin;
                this.end = end;
                this.angle = angle;
                this.strokeW = strokeW;
                this.color = color;
          }
         display() {
             stroke(this.color);
             strokeWeight(this.strokeW);
             line(this.begin.x, this.begin.y, this.end.x, this.end.y);
          }
          right(angle) {
                let direction = p5.Vector.sub(this.end, this.begin);
                direction.rotate(angle);
                let nextPoint = p5.Vector.add(direction, this.end);  
                let right = new Branch(this.end, nextPoint, this.strokeW*0.7, this.color.levels.map(x =>  x * 0.9));  //this line of code throw an error once I am trying to manipulate on the array
                return right;
          }
    }

    let tree = [];
    let trunk;
    let something;  //just for check how looks like a p5.color object
    function setup() {
          createCanvas(400, 400);
          background(20);
          something = color(100, 230, 100);
          console.log(something);
          let x = createVector(width/2, height);
          let y = createVector(width/2, height-100);
          trunk = new Branch(x,y, 7, color(255,100, 100));
          tree[0] = trunk;
          tree.push(trunk);
    }

    function draw() {
                for(let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
                      tree[i].display(); 
                }
    }

    function mousePressed() {

          for(let i = tree.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tree.push(tree[i].right(Math.PI/4, 0.66));
          }    
    }
```

Comment: this.color.levels.map(x =>  x * 0.9) return levels array not Color. Maybe color(this.color.levels.map(x =>  x * 0.9))is what you need I don't know p5.js so you have to look how you modify levels properly.

Comment: I am really not a graphics guru :P. Cant help with this. you should close this and open a new question maybe at computer graphics section and a proper grpahics person can help you.

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/changing-stroke-colour-using-recursion/4951

Comment: what are you trying to do with the colors here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your use of map. You are doing:

```
this.col.levels.map(x =>  x * 0.9)
```

which returns an array, not a p5.Color object.
To create the new color object, instead use:

```
color.apply(this, this.col.levels.map(x =>  x * 0.9))
```

You can see the full sketch [here](https://editor.p5js.org/rednoyz/sketches/S1r8zxXpQ)